# How to change selection highlight colour of a ListBoxItem in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to change the selection highlight color of a ListBoxItem
[image]

The split view pane on the left has a ListBox containing the ListBoxItems.The default selection colour is blue and I want to customize it but I'm not able to change it.

I couldn't find any property to change the selection highlight color of a ListBoxItem in UWP.

Comment: for future style coding you can simply drag and drop the control and right click on the control --> Edit template --> Edit copy --> press ok and now you can see the style will get added to the xaml code and now you can edit this template as how you want :) now you just have to copy that style code and paste it on in your Appx.xaml file and use it in all application by the key :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the **style** of ListBoxItem to change the selection highlight color.In the style,you should change all the states that contanin '`Selected`' key word to change the Fill property to the color you want(I change the color to the Red like below).

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full"/>
                            <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="Transparent" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource BodyContentPresenterStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then set the style to the ListBox.

```
<ListBox Width="100" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}">
```

Comment: bro, i added this to a resource dictionary but im getting errors saying The specified value cannot be assigned for all tags including style tag

Answer (score 2):

You can custom the `ListViewItem` style of `ListView`, which can be found in `generic.xaml`, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic\generic.xaml`. The path may be different, but you can serach.

In `generic.xaml`, you can see all control's template. Then search `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemRevealStyle">`, copy this whole style, and new a resource dictionary called `ListViewItem.xaml`. The file should like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemRevealStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        x:Name="Root"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                        FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                        CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                        CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                        DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}"
                        DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                        FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                        FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                        PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                        PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                        PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                        SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"
                        SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}"
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                        PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                        SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}"
                        RevealBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}"
                        RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}"
                        RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrush}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ListViewItemPresenter>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In this file search `SelectedBackground`, if you want to change background to orange, then write SelectedBackground="Orange". Also note another property called `SelectedPointerOverBackground`, you can also change the value as you wish.

After all this done, add `ListViewItem.xaml` to `App.xaml`, so the app can recognize your own style. The `App.xaml` should like this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ListViewItem.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then change your ListView item style to

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemRevealStyle}">
```

Bingo, Press F5 to build and run.

The above steps maybe a little complicated, but it worth. Later you may want wo change a TextBox' style or something else, you can also follow this tutorial.

Comment: Bro I asked for ListBox

Comment: Oh, my.......But for ListBoxItem, you can also follow the above steps, and pay attention to <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"><VisualState x:Name="Selected"><VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"><VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver"><VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">, just as Faywang - MSFT wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to skin your listboxes is to define the corresponding brushes in app.xaml, just add something like the following in your Application element:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <!--
        To workout the names of the brushes you need to lookup the relevant control in the following file:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic\generic.xaml
        For instance ListBoxItem
        -->            
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <!-- Selected & SelectedUnfocused -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="#11FFFFFF" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="#11FFFFFF" />
                <!-- SelectedPointerOver -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush" Color="#11FFFFFF" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush" Color="#11FFFFFF" />
                <!-- SelectedPressed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush" Color="#11FFFFFF" />
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <!-- Selected & SelectedUnfocused -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="#11000000" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="#11000000" />
                <!-- SelectedPointerOver -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush" Color="#11000000" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush" Color="#11000000" />
                <!-- SelectedPressed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush" Color="#11000000" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```