# How to disable listbox hover effect?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have googled lots of things but I couldn't find out can someone please explain me how to disable this disgusting effect
code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="HistoryList" Margin="10" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBoxItem>asd</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
```

ı have tried `focusable = false` and

```
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

but when I do this items doesn't show. Please help me

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549057/how-to-change-selection-highlight-colour-of-a-listboxitem-in-uwp). 1 minute of Google. :)

Comment: actually that didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You must set `ControlTemplate.TargetType` property.  Otherwise the template won't be loaded.

> "Also note that the TargetType property is required on a
>   ControlTemplate if the template definition contains a
>   ContentPresenter."   [Microsoft Docs: ControlTemplate.TargetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.targettype?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <ContentPresenter />
          </Border>

          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before and had success to remove the hover effect.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" /> 
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

This will allow you to have a LisBox that looks like an itemscontrol, but still has support for selection if you want it.